# 'Execute failed:unauthorized' when using RockMongo with MongoLab

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I can't use RockMongo(v1.1.2) to connect MongoLab, what did i do wrong?

In my MDb.php file

```
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_name"] = "MongoLab";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_host"] = "ds053xx.mongolab.com";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_port"] = "53818";
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_timeout"] = 0;
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = true;
```

and when I log in with my username, password, db_name

It can log in but I can't do anything with it
on the left side of the screen it show

```
    Execute failed:unauthorized
    function (){ return db.getCollectionNames(); }
```

I have no problem when connect to local database. 
And also can use the same url,port,username,etc. with MongoVUE

Comment: Add clusterAdmin role to the user you login as in the admin database. Restart mongo.

Comment: Is it possible to do that on MongoLab?, any link for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be anything you're doing wrong. It looks like RockMongo requires admin access because it's trying to list collections for databases other than your own (such as the admin and local databases), which is not possible w/ MongoLab's Sandbox databases.

https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access only your own database, you can change the following line 31 inside `rockmongo/apps/models/MDb.php` `listCollections(MongoDB $db)` function:

from

```
$names = self::exec($db, 'function () {
    return db.getCollectionNames();
 }');
```

to

```
$names = $db->getCollectionNames();
```